# Arinc429 32 bit words

Tags: c, hex

So I have started a new project at work which is introducing a lot of new concepts.

I'm using the arinc429 USB box and c and need to read information coming in from the buffer, which is fine, it's what to do with the data I get afterwards I'm having a little trouble with.

With each data item in the buffer I get a arinc_low and arinc_high unsigned longs which both represent the end and beginning of a hex value. How do I take these two hex values, put them together and construct the 32 bit word so I can retrieve what I need, for example, bits 1-8 are used for the Label etc.

So far I have the following:

```
snprintf(low, 16, "%lx", buffer[i].arinc_low);
snprintf(high, 16, "%lx", buffer[i].arinc_high);
```

Through which I can iterate the resulting chars:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(low);i++)
{
    printf("%d", low[i]);
}
```

etc.

The results im getting for example are:

```
102 55 102 -24 ......
```

Are these the bits that make up the 32 bit word that I am after, from looking at the documentation it would seem that these are sensible numbers to be getting back. Like I said, this project really brings in a lot of new concepts for me that I have glanced at fleetingly in the past, but never really put into practical use.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See also the help pages (linked at the top of every page) for how to write a good question.

Comment: More information added.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a look at bitwise operators. Especially right and left shift operators (watch your Endianness) in order to, for example, set a variable to `arinc_high` and then to move it accordingly. Then you will be setting the remaining part with bitwise OR, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, would this be the correct way to join the two shorts (I got the datatype wrong in my original comment) `unsigned long combo(unsigned short n1, unsigned short n2)
{
    return n1 << 16 | n2;
}`

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it should work. Since you're using all unsigned you're good to go, but as an extra information just be careful when left shift and signed values are mixed as it results in undefined behaviour, AFAIK.